# How to use mongoid-rspec gem properly?

Tags: ruby, rspec, mongoid

Following [instructions](https://github.com/evansagge/mongoid-rspec#installation) I have installed *mongoid-rspec* and configured it in spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Mongoid::Matchers, type: :model
end
```

But came across an issue with the simplest test

```
describe City do
  it { should have_many(:locations) }
end

City should have many :locations
     Failure/Error: it { should have_many(:locations) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `has_many?' for
```

Seems I'm doing it wrong, but can't figure out what's exactly wrong.

The models are pretty simple

```
class City
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  include Mongoid::Versioning
  max_versions 10

  has_many :locations
end

class Location
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :city
  field :name, type: String
end
```

One last thing, I don't use Rails.

Comment: show you `city.rb` or city model

Comment: added them to the description

Comment: is your spec file located in `spec/models` ?

Comment: I don't have that folder since I don't use Rails.

Comment: Have you maybe tried to setup it like I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across similar issue but whilst working on rails, solution for both rails and none rails I believe are very similar:

```
gem 'mongoid-rspec', '~> 2.2.0'
```

**Without rails**

Add to your spec_helper.rb file:

```
require 'mongoid-rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Mongoid::Matchers
end
```

**With rails**

Add to your rails_helper.rb

```
require 'mongoid-rspec'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Mongoid::Matchers, type: :model
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In my spec_helper file i removed the option type: :model and it now works

`RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Mongoid::Matchers
end`